# PHP Regex not matching polish characters

Tags: php, regex

This code doesn't return any matches when I type "szukaj/zwierzęta" in the url path, but when I type "szukaj/zwierzeta" it works.

```
<?php 
$url =  "http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}";
$rules = array( 
  'film'  => "/film/(?'film_slug'[^/]+)-(?'film_id'\d+)",
  'szukaj' => "/szukaj/(?'query'[\w\-]+)",
);

foreach ( $rules as $action => $rule ) {
  if ( preg_match( '~^'.$rule.'$~i', $uri, $params ) ) {
        switch($action)
        {
           case 'szukaj': (doesn't work with ęąćźż, works with others)
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried with 'szukaj' => "/szukaj/(?'query'[\pL|\pN-]+)",

but it didn't work.

Comment: Try adding unicode flag `(?u)` at the beginning of your regex. If it doesn't work try adding `u` flag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `[a-zA-ZąćęłńóśźżĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻ-]` to mach any a-zA-Z **and** any polish special char.

Here is the usage inside your code:

```
<?php 
$url =  "http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}";
$rules = array( 
  'film'  => "/film/(?'film_slug'[^/]+)-(?'film_id'\d+)",
  'szukaj' => "/szukaj/(?'query'[+a-zA-ZąćęłńóśźżĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻ-]+)",
);

foreach ( $rules as $action => $rule ) {
  if ( preg_match( '~^'.$rule.'$~i', $uri, $params ) ) {
        switch($action)
        {
           case 'szukaj': (doesn't work with ęąćźż, works with others)
        }
    }
}
```

And regex101 example:
https://regex101.com/r/F0uiDE/1

Comment: Yeah I just did that, but now I want to that query also include the + sign, like in url I have: "zwierzęta+są" doesn't return matches, zwierzęta does and są also

Comment: Can you give the example of the URL? I'm not sure I understand

Comment: szukaj/zwierzęta+są+inne
on that regex101.com it works, in php it does not. using this:
`\/szukaj\/(?'query'[a-zA-Z\+ąćęłńóśźżĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻ-]+)`

Comment: Thanks, but found another solution. Forgot I had url_decode with converted + to ' ' (whitespace). Added \s to regex and now works. Thank you very much for your help.